# FlatMap Traversable Ones Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have this code below:

```
//TABLE FROM HIve
val df = hiveContext.sql("select * from test_table where date ='20160721' LIMIT 300")
//ERROR ON THE LINE BELOW
val row = df.flatMap(row => ((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1))
```

I get this error in the code above saying:

```
Type mismatch, expected: (Row) => Traversable[NotInferedU], actual : (Row) => ((Any, Any, Any), Int)
```

Can someone check to see what is wrong in my flatMap function. I am not able to understand what this error is stating.

Comment: What do you expect your code to do? The error is (rightly) telling you that `((Any, Any, Any), Int)` doesn't correspond to something of the form `Traversable[..]`.

Comment: Can you try: `val row = df.flatMap(row => ((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1).productIterator)`   That should convert the tuple to an iterator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably should use `map` instead.  `((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1)` is not a `Traversable` as the error message stated.

Comment: Aren't tuples convertable to a traversable: `((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1).productIterator` I did some testing in repl and the flatMap worked.

Comment: not sure what OP wants to achieve, instead of using the `productorIterator` you can just `row => List((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1)` in `flatMap`

Comment: @ryan Oh right I realized the return type of flatMap has to be traversable. But the thing is if I do you stated with the `row => List((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1)` will that be flatted out to `( (row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1), (row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1), (row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1) )`

Comment: or will it be like `( List((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1), List((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1), List((row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2)), 1) )`